# MySQL multiple instance on CentOS controlled by same service

Tags: mysql

I want to run 2 separate mysql instances on CentoS which could be stopped and started separately on different ports and have totally separate databases

My /etc/my.cnf is:

```
[mysqld]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
port            = 3306
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
```

My /etc/my2.cnf is as follows:

```
[mysqld2]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql2
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock

user=mysql
Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
#symbolic-links=0

[mysqld2]
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql2.sock
port            = 3307
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql2


[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld2.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld2.pid
```

When I start mysqld service, even mysqld2 gets started and they both show same databases. I can connect to mysql on both 3306 and 3307 ports.

service mysqld status and service mysqld2 status show to be using same pid

How do I have 2 completely different mysqls and mysqld2 services, runninf on 3306 and 3307 port separately, which could be stopped and started totally separately?

Comment: mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
|  2 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | NULL  | SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST |
+----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+

Comment: 'SHOW GLOBAL STATUS' is very long output. Should I paste it here?

Comment: both the *.cnf are pasted in the question completely

Comment: Still willing to invest time in your analysis, after you post ulimit -a, SGS x 2, ,SGV x 2 and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;  Have a Merry Christmas.